# How to use CreateHardLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes) with a relative path for target?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, hardlink

Using

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool CreateHardLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, 
string lpTargetFileName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);
```

should I be able to use a relative path for the lpTargetFileName?

It doesn't seem to work for me. Should it?
It works with full paths.

***Edit:***

This is Windows 7 and/or 2008

Comment: Surprisingly enough, MSDN is silent on the topic. Which Windows version?

Comment: Usually most APIs work with a relative file path; what is the GetLastError() value?  I would use absolute paths with APIs like this just to be safe, though.

Comment: I am not sure, but the lpTargetFileName might be interpreted relative to the lpSymlinkFilename, i.e. it works much like a symlink, not a hardlink.